# Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 (SM-T110) missing tethering option

Tags: tethering, samsung-galaxy-tab-3

I just got my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 (SM-T110). I want to tether my tab to my PC, but I can't find the tether option under more settings.

How to fix it?

Comment: I have similar problem with Samsung Galaxy Tablet S7 FE, the tether option is nowhere to be found :(

Answer (score 0):

Search it properly under the more settings option or use the [wifi tethering app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=og.android.tether&hl=en) to tether your device.

Comment: I've search it properly like 10 times. I go through everything, checked 1 by 1 and cant find it. I've tried easy tether app, I cant find the solution to the error. The error is no connection

Comment: Hi, note that the app is not available on the Play Store anymore (you may still be able to see the entry on the Play Store if you have installed it before).

Answer (score 0):

Download [WiFi Tether Router](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.snclab.wifitetherrouter) by Fabio Grasso (costs $2), it's well worth it. You need to be rooted and have your WiFi turned on before you Enable Wifi Router.

Config settings for Sprint Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 SM-T217S:

- Interface wlan0
- Method 3 - HostApd
- Encryption wpa2-psk or open (your choice)
- Channel 1
- Drivers nl80211
- ApType master
- "HostApd Patch" <- UNCHECKED

Hope this helps, it takes me a few tries with settings and a few apps to figure which one worked.